# WPF Commands vs. event trigger commands

Tags: wpf, button, eventtrigger, icommand

In a WPF `Button` we have a `Command` parameter which can be binded to `ICommand`.

```
<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
```

We can also use `EventTriggers` with `InvokeCommandAction` to fire a `ICommand`.

```
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

What is the difference between them and when to use which?

Update:

I have noticed difference in the following scenario:

- I have a textbox which validates using IValudationRule if the textbox is empty.
- I added MultiDataTrigger condition to have the IsEnabled property of a save button to be set to false when the Validation.HasError equals to true.

Using the Button Command all works good, but using the EventTrigger it doesn`t work.

Any reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snippets you provide are almost the same,if you don't use `CanExecute`. `InvokeCommandAction` is not native `WPF` class, it is created in `Interaction` library for the cases when control doesn't provide `Command` and you have to bind Command to some event. for example when you need command on `ListBox.SelectionChanged` or etc.

So based on above, my suggestion is, always use Command if it is possible, and use `EventTrigger` only when you can't go without it.

Also Note, than `ICommand` also provide `CanExecute` based of which button can enable/disable, which will not work in second case

Comment: Are you sure the Interaction library does not wireup the enabled/disabled automatically?

Comment: hmmm, not sure, but do you mean it wireup in case of click even or any other event? I don't think it is true to disable control, if I bind SelectedChanged event for example

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight difference (CanExecute), but other than that, it's just a matter of what part of the code is subscribing you to the event/command. An `ICommand` exposes the `Execute` and `CanExecute` methods, so...

`ButtonBase`'s Command property will automatically relay Click events to the command's Execute event and change it's disabled/endabled property based on the command's CanExecute being raised... under the hood (you don't have to worry about wireup).

The `Interaction` library does the same thing, but exposes various classes to allow you to "build" your own wireup in a simple fashion. You're basically creating a couple of classes that say "Wire the *Event Name* (ButtonBase.Click) event to call the ICommand.Execute method of the *Specified Command* (SomeCommand)."

In fact, if you forgo both of these options you could even roll your own in code-behind... but then again, there is no point in that (other than to learn how it works) when it is offered in a nice, clean, under-the-hood way, unit-tested, optimized way?